# How to capture group specific messages with OutputDestination?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, integration-testing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

We have integration tests that end up dispatching many messages on the same destination, but many different groups. In rabbitMQ terms, same exchange with different topics.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.userEdited-out-0.destination=user.exchange
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.userEdited-out-0.producer.routing-key-expression='user-edited.v1'
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.userEdited-out-0.content-type=application/json

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.userCreated-out-0.destination=user.exchange
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.userCreated-out-0.producer.routing-key-expression='user-created.v1'
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.userCreated-out-0.content-type=application/json
```

I have been successful with reading these messages using OutputDestination, but it appears that I'm only able to pull messages sent to a destination (exchange), and not able to also filter by the group (topic) it was sent to.

Is there any way to pull messages from the OutputDestination by destination and group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct and is by design, since grouping is specific to a binder implementation (i.e., rabbit) OR part of native functionality of the broker (kafka).
So the test binder is designed to ensure that all core components involved in receiving and sending messages are tested.

Comment: So in the situation where we have many messages sent to the same destination with different groups where I want to inspect a specific one, do you recommend that I set some field like "type" on the messages to be able to filter them by?

Comment: Perhaps, but remember, you should only test your components and that they are functioning in the context of a generic binder. Testing binder's specific functionality is our responsibility. In other words if something doesn't work there would be nothing for you to fix other than possibly submitting an issue

Comment: It's not so much that we are trying to test binder specific functionality. I trust that it will be sent to the proper place, it is more of that we have a contracts with other teams via messaging, and we want to verify that the proper messages are sent in our integration tests (since messaging is part of the public portion of our API). We previously used to use MessageCollector which allowed capturing per Output binding, but now that is gone, we are trying to find the best substitute. Thanks again for all your help!